# Monostable (eg CD4538 channel) connecting rise and fall inputs together to generate pulse from rise or fall

Tags: trigger, monostable

I would like to use one channel of a dual monostable (CD4538) to generate a pulse from either a rise or fall single trigger input feed.
If I connect rise and fall trigger inputs together
(or use a diode to ensure input B is always higher than input A
with input signal fed to input B),
will this produce an output pulse when triggered from either a rise or fall input?

Comment: Have you thought about using a simulator?

Comment: It is probably about time I had a simulator, especially now that I am retired.
I have a small drawer cabinet with components for umpteen projects.
I also have an old prototyping breadboard that I shall use to experiment..
Thanks for responding.
If anyone else wants an answer to this question, let me know and I will post experiment results.

Answer (score 1):

> *I would like to use one channel of a dual monostable (CD4538) to
> generate a pulse from either a rise or fall single trigger input feed.*

I don't think your proposed circuit idea will work but, you can use an exclusive-or gate to produce a short pulse whenever the input signal changes state. This can then be used as it is (i.e. without a monostable) or used with a conventional monostable circuit. The ex-or circuit I'm talking about is called an "edge detector". This one uses an ex-or gate and two inverters: -

[image]

Images from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/270903/20218). Or, you can extend the pulse width using a Schmitt-trigger ex-or and an RC delay: -

[image]

By extending the RC time delay (and using a Schmitt-trigger ex-or) you can implement the monostable time delay i.e. make the pulse wider.