# Is there a minimum voltage for digital logic (eg XOR) in CircuitLab?

Tags: logic-gates, circuitlab

I am trying to design an edge to glitch converter (XOR time delay) that works at 3 V.

For context: This is to wake an ESP8266 when a sensor value changes. I am fairly certain at this point that the ESP8266 can't interrupt for deep sleep wake on either edge. I have done this successfully with a [dual edge monostable](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/649205/how-do-i-wake-an-mcu-when-a-float-sensor-value-changes) but wanted to try using an [edge to glitch converter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/270908/288848).

My simulation works well enough at 5 V, though I wasn't able to simulate using the 56 pF cap and 1 k resistor that Olin's design uses.

[image: Input]
[image: Output]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz2Jdu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, when I change Vcc to 3 V, the output signal stops triggering on the edge.

[image: Output at 3V]

Is the solution simply to change the values of my components, or is it because of a limitation in CircuitLab's XOR gate?

I'm planning to use a SOT-23 XOR for the design (probably something like [MC74VHC1GT86](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1577687.pdf) which apparently can be used with 3 V circuits).

Edit: The CircuitLab docs don’t seem to mention the term “[xor](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Acircuitlab.com%2Fdocs%2F%20xor)”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.circuitlab.com/docs/circuit-elements/#digital) for CircuitLab:

> Digital Elements
>
> All digital inputs are ground-relative, and have input hysteresis:
> VIL=2.0 volts, VIH=3.0 volts.
>
> All digital outputs are ground-relative, and are either 0 or 5V, in
> series with a 10 Ω output impedance.
>
> These input and output parameters are currently not configurable.
>
> Neither digital inputs nor digital outputs provide the sort of
> diode-based clamping one would expect to see on any IC's digital I/O
> pin. If your circuit depends on that, add diodes explicitly.

Comment: Aha, thanks. I was searching the docs for “xor” and didn’t find anything. I didn’t think to use a broader term.